# Excel VBA Find text in a formula and select that cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to *check a cell* for *specific text* in a formula.

If it contains that text I want to select the next cell.

If it doesn't contain that text I want to perform some formatting.

I have tried

```
If StrComp("A1", "D:\I Stuff\Ser*", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
'this is checking that "D:\I Stuff\Ser" does exist in A1...
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("A1:H1").Select
```

It doesn't seem to *select/find* the string in the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) should be used to check for the string within the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx).

```
dim rng as range
set rng = activecell
if cbool(instr(1, rng.formula, "D:\I Stuff\Ser", vbTextCompare)) Then
    rng.resize(1, 8).Select
else
    'not found. do something else
end if
```

You may also be interested in [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Thanks for the reading references, that helps immensely. So using the above code I get a compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference. If I remove the "." from ".Range" the macro runs. However, It is referencing cell A1 when I need the ActiveCell to be the starting point. How do I set the active cell as the beginning of the Range?

Comment: I've adjusted the code to reference the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174738%28v=office.11%29.aspx) as the starting point. Sorry about the extra `.` in `.range`. My bad. I'm just so used to not using activate that I wrote it as if it was within a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).